# Alterar comportamento do botão de acordo com a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Como posso mudar o comportamento de um botão de acordo com a URL? tenho a seguinte URL, ex:

> site.com/search/***maquina de subir ladeira***

o botão seria algo para filtrar de acordo com o preço, sendo **crescente** ou **decrescente**.

**Exemplo com "DESC" decrescente (maior preço)**

URL:

> site.com/search/**maquina de subir ladeira** *?filter=desc*

Sendo o botão o aposto da URL:

```
<a href="site.com/search/maquina de subir ladeira?filter=asc">Filtrar por menor preço</a>
```

ou, para valores crescentes:

**Exemplo com "ASC" crescente (menor preço)**

> site.com/search/**maquina de subir ladeira** *?filter=asc*

```
<a href="site.com/search/maquina de subir ladeira?filter=desc">Filtrar por maior preço</a>
```

sendo o comportamente padrão (sem filtro ?filter na URL) **"filtrar por menor preço"**

Comment: O que você quer fazer é usar AJAX, certo? E então modificar algum conteúdo da página?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que seja o que você procura:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var get = document.URL;
    if(get.match(/filter=asc/i)){
       //Faz isso
    }
    else if(get.match(/filter=desc/i)){
       //Faz aquilo
    }
    else{
       //Faz outra  coisa
    }
});
```

Comment: Entretanto, considerando que você está passando a variavel de controle do ordenamento via GET você deveria considerar a possibilidade de processar o código via linguagem de programação da sua página ao invés de JS.